# Send bulk mail using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013, macros

Was working on a project which will be sending bulk mail to different people if the conditions are met.

Conditions :

- Column U contains the final status (Open or WIP) (will not send if
  Closed no matter if current date is larger)
- Column Q contains Closure date. Which when compared to current date,
  if less then automatic shooting mails to people.

I had tried to do with for loop but its giving shooting 4 mails with same To and CC. And not going to the next row to compare.

Cell comparison V2 with Q2, then next loop V3 with Q3 and on the same hand check if the cell U2 has "Open"

Thank you in advance.

Code as below:

```
Sub Data_RoundedRectangle1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim StrBody As String



On Error Resume Next

For i = 1 to 4

If Sheets("Data").Range("U2:U6").Value2 = "Open" Or     Sheets("Data").Range("U2:U6").Value2 = "WIP" And (CDate(Cells(2, 17).Value) <     Now()) Then



        Set rng = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        'Only the visible cells in the selection
        Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        'You can also use a fixed range if you want
        Set rng = Sheets("Checklist").Range("A2:B25").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0


        With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next

With OutMail


        If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, "C").Value2 = "Operation_Support" And Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, "E").Value2 = "Quality_Assurance" Then


     StrBody = "Hi," & "<br>" & _


.To = "a"

.CC = "b"
.BCC = ""
.Subject = ""
.HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng)
.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
'.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
.Display
'.Send

ElseIf Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, "C").Value = "Operation_Support" And Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, "E").Value = "Analytics" Then

StrBody = "Hi," & "<br>" & _
      "PFB the process details which requires your attention." & "<br>" & _
      "The review for this process has crossed over due." & "<br>" & _
      "Please ask the process owner to review the Process Manuals and Maps."     & "<br><br><br>"

.To = "c"

.CC = "d"
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Process Manual and Maps Review is Overdue"
.HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng)
.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
'.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
.Display
'.Send

End If

    End With

    i = i + 1
    Exit For

    End If
End If

Next r

On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Next x
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: @MehulRastogi You seem to have created two accounts for yourself. Go [here](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge them

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of your loop

```
For i = 1 to 4
```

But you never reference `i`, so it's doing *everything* four times. You should use it like this instead -

```
If Sheets("Data").cells(21,1+i).Value2 = "Open" Or Sheets("Data").cells(21,1+i).Value2 = "WIP" And ...
```

I'm not entirely sure what the second part of your `if` is referring to, but you get the gist.